# SVI implied vol model parameterization

Tags: finance

It would be nice if anybody could help me. 
I'm trying to understand the raw SVI parameterization of Gatheral. 
We have: $$\omega(k; \chi_R)=a+b \left\{\rho(k-m)+ \sqrt{(k-m)^2+ \sigma^2}\right\} $$
I'm not clear about what exactly is given to calculate this and how to determine the parameters. 
Can anybody explain me this, please?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In the SVI model, you are modeling the implied volatility $\omega$ (at a fixed time) as a function of the strike $k$, with other parameters $a, b, \rho, m, \sigma^2$ fixed.

The way you compute this is, given a bunch of quotes at the same maturity, run numerical optimization to calibrate the parameters, and once they are fixed, you have implied vol as a one-dimensional function of the strike $k$.

**UPDATE**

Here is a practical guide to do this.

Implement the functions

1. *BSvol2price* -- straight-forward implementation of the BS formula calculations
2. *BSprice2vol* -- rootfinder inversion of the calculation above, matching the vol to produce a given price

Now you have 2 options, both using multi-dimensional numerical optimization:

- **fit in vol space** - convert incoming price quotes to vols (using *BSprice2vol*), and fit the parameters to the resulting vols
- **fit in price space** -- fit the parameters by producing prices from vols and measuring errors in price

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86716/discussion-on-answer-by-gt6989b-svi-implied-vol-model-parameterization).